# How can I map a numpy array into another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays. A 3D or 2D array `reference` and a 3D array `map_`.

In this example let Reference be

```
reference = array([[ [11,12,13], [14,15,16], [17,18,19] ],
                   [ [21,22,23], [24,25,26], [27,28,29] ],
                   [ [31,32,33], [34,35,36], [37,38,39] ],
                   [ [41,42,43], [44,45,46], [47,48,49] ]])
```

An let map be

```
map_ = array([[ [0,0], [1,2], [2,2] ],
              [ [2,1], [3,2], [3,0] ]])
```

The result should be

```
array([[ [11,12,13], [27,28,29], [37,38,39] ],
       [ [24,25,36], [47,48,49], [41,42,43] ]])
```

I can solve it as:

```
array([[reference[i[0],i[1],:] for i in j] for j in map_])
```

However when map_ and reference are arrays of thousands by thousands, this become very slow.

Is there a fastest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use advanced indexing:

```
result = reference[map[:,:,0], map[:,:,1]]
```

(BTW refrain from using keyword `map` as variable name...)

Timing:

```
import timeit
%timeit test = np.array([[reference[i[0],i[1],:] for i in j] for j in mp])
# 4.53 µs ± 72.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit test = reference[mp[:,:,0], mp[:,:,1]]
# 1.64 µs ± 4.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

The gain will likely be more substantial on larger arrays... E.g. with `map = np.random.randint(0,3,size=(100,100,2))` we get

```
4.11 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

v.s.

```
98.5 µs ± 200 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Julien's answer but using tuple indexing. You just need to have the dimensions of `map_` in the correct order:

```
reference[tuple(np.moveaxis(map_, 2, 0))]
```

Output:

```
array([[[11, 12, 13],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [37, 38, 39]],

       [[34, 35, 36],
        [47, 48, 49],
        [41, 42, 43]]])
```

I.e. you could directly use `reference[tuple(map_)]` if `map_` was:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 0]]])
```

Comment: This seems a tiny wee bit slower than my solution (on big arrays), however it becomes pretty much identical if you use `map_.transpose((2,0,1)))` rather than `np.moveaxis(map_, 2, 0))`...

Comment: Thanks @Julien that's indeed another possibility, I hadn't timed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Julien's answer is more concise and should be accepted for this question. I spent some time writing this answer so I will leave it here as 1. I took time writing it and 2. others might find something in this (who knows)

Short form here. Find the long form below:

```
reference = array([[ [11,12,13], [14,15,16], [17,18,19] ],
                   [ [21,22,23], [24,25,26], [27,28,29] ],
                   [ [31,32,33], [34,35,36], [37,38,39] ],
                   [ [41,42,43], [44,45,46], [47,48,49] ]])
idx = array([
    [[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2]],
    [[2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 0]]
])
xd, yd = idx.shape[0], idx.shape[1]
zd = reference.shape[2]

idx = idx.reshape((xd * yd, 2))
indexed_reference = reference[idx[:,0], idx[:, 1]].reshape((xd, yd, zd))
print(indexed_reference)
```

First, reshape your map to a 2d array to make it easy for indexing. Note I will use `idx` instead of `map` as `map` is a predefined function in python:

```
idx = array([
    [[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2]],
    [[2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 0]]
])
# idx.shape -> (2, 3, 2), make this (6,2). not reshaped dimensions' product must be constant. 2x3x3 == 6x2
# you can probably also (multiply the first two, last) if you want to make it generic
reshaped_idx = idx.reshape((6,2))
# reshaped_idx = array([[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 0]])

# now just use the indexes to map the original array
reference = array([[ [11,12,13], [14,15,16], [17,18,19] ],
                   [ [21,22,23], [24,25,26], [27,28,29] ],
                   [ [31,32,33], [34,35,36], [37,38,39] ],
                   [ [41,42,43], [44,45,46], [47,48,49] ]])

indexed_reference = reference[reshaped_idx[:,0], reshaped_idx[:,1]]
# array([
#      [11, 12, 13], [27, 28, 29], [37, 38, 39], 
#      [34, 35, 36], [47, 48, 49], [41, 42, 43]
# ])

# indexed_reference.shape -> (6,3) -> 6x3 = 18
# reshape this to the original idx
indexed_reference_reshaped = indexed_reference.reshape((2,3,3))
# answer: array([
#    [[11, 12, 13],[27, 28, 29], [37, 38, 39]],
#    [[34, 35, 36],[47, 48, 49], [41, 42, 43]]
# ])
```